# How to sort a DataGrid column by a different property

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid, which

```
<DataGrid Name="grid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding StudentName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Percentage" 
            Binding="{Binding PercentageDisplayValue}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here's the object class:

```
internal class DgObject
{
    public DgObject(string _student, double _percent)
    {
        StudentName = _student;
        Percentage = _percent;
    }
    public string StudentName { get; }

    public double Percentage { get; }
    public string PercentageDisplayValue => Percentage.ToString("F") + "%";
}
```

**The question is, how can I bind a property to a column that will not be displayed** (in this case "Percentage")**, but will be used only as a sorting variable?** Thank you.

Comment: Of course you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data grid columns have a [SortMemberPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.sortmemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx) property. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: That's what I've been missing. Thank you.